# How to make synchronous socket asynchronous?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have to use a socket library that only exposes synchronous socket interface. I have a few question converting this sync to async. I start from msdn sample(the library interface is similar to microsoft socket library except that the library uses different communication algorithm).

This is my current progress

```
    private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log("Start server");
        var port = int.Parse(Port.Text);
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
            // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the 
            // host running the application.
            Log("Hostname " + Dns.GetHostName());

            IPAddress[] ipv4Addresses = Array.FindAll(
                Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList,
                a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            IPAddress[] ipv6Addresses = Array.FindAll(
                Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList,
                a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6);

            foreach (var ip in ipv4Addresses)
            {
                Log("Ipv4 list " + ip);
            }
            foreach (var ip in ipv6Addresses)
            {
                Log("Ipv6 list " + ip);
            }

            var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            Log("Ip " + IPAddress.Any);
            Log("Port " + port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and 
            // listen for incoming connections.
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);
                Log("Max connection " + (int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);

                // Start listening for connections.
                bool isContinue = true;
                while (isContinue)
                {
                    Log("Waiting for a connection...");
                    // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
                    var handler = listener.Accept();


                    // handle connection
                    // Data buffer for incoming data.
                    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

                    string data;

                    Log("Connection accepted");

                    Log("Local endpoint " + handler.LocalEndPoint);
                    Log("Remote endpoint " + handler.RemoteEndPoint);

                    data = null;

                    // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
                    while (true)
                    {
                        bytes = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                        if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Show the data on the console.
                    Log("Text received " + data);

                    // Echo the data back to the client.
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    handler.Send(msg);
                    Log("Message sent");

                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    Log("Shutdown");
                    handler.Close();
                    Log("Close");

                    isContinue = true;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log(ex.ToString());
            }
        });
        await task;
    }
```

1. What happened when i have 2 or more concurrent client?
2. What happened to the second connection when the first connection is busy communicating?
3. Does the listener immediately listen after listener.Accept()?
4. Assuming i have 4 logical cores, what happen when i listen on 4 thread each with different port number. Each of this listener is blocking the thread in listener.Accept. What will happened to my ui and pc? Will it hang(all cores are used and blocked)?
5. Are there any pattern that i can refer on?

Im thinking of using Task, async, await, but i cant seem to construct that in my head.

I want to improve this library by adding socket.

Thanks.

Comment: [Awaiting Socket Operations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx)

Comment: So does this 3rd party library expose `Begin/End` style of API?

Comment: If that code is from MSDN they should take that code down. Unsafe disposal, ASCII encoding, strange DNS stuff without a point. Don't trust MSDN too much.

Comment: @Noseratio None. Only Accept, Send and Receive(plus few others, none async).

Comment: @usr I have to agree with you in that regard.

Answer (score 4):

If the library only exposes a synchronous implementation that means that it is performing blocking I/O. Since you can't change that as it is part of the library's implementation, you will have to make use of ThreadPool threads to delegate work. I have written a couple of blog posts that provide context into this ([1](http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2013/08/02/asynchronous-io-in-c-introduction/), [2](http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2013/10/29/asynchronous-io-in-c-io-completion-ports/)).

Handling this work asynchronously would only make sense cases when you want to specifically avoid blocking a particular thread, such as a UI thread. In that case, you can simply perfom calls to the socket library like this:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => 
  { 
     // run socket code
  });

var result = await task;
// rest of your code
```

The call to `Task.Run` queues work to the ThreadPool and awaiting avoids blocking the UI thread while that work is performed in a separate thread.

Comment: Using thread pool for naturally async operations is a bad idea, if it can  be avoided: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx

Comment: @Noseratio I totally agree. That is why I clarified that this should be done because the library is blocking and only if a particular thread cannot be blocked. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: It does makes sense. I didn't realize there's a 3rd party library involved as the OP only uses standard sockets in his code. I now up-voted your answer.

Comment: @Noseratio and others. The library i used is synchronous only and uses standard .net socket like implementation(different from .net but similar in usage method.)

Comment: @DamianSchenkelman Should I wrap listener.Accept with Task Run? Is that the best method?

Comment: @publicENEMY again, it depends on whether you are trying to make sure that the UI thread is still responsive or not. If you are, then yes. Otherwise it depends on why you are trying to make this call asynchronous from the caller's perspective.

Comment: @DamianSchenkelman the issue is not how to make it async. the issue is how to develop a async socket server with only sync method(accept,send,receive). The biggest problem i have right now is how can i accept connection asynchronously.

Comment: @publicENEMY Does the async socket server need to be asynchronous in the sense that it needs to perform non-blocking I/O? That is not going to happen, since as you said, the library is synchronous. Have you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx? The only thing that you can do is avoid blocking a particular thread or set of threads and dispatch work to background threads. This is what I wrote in my answer, but I don't think we are understanding each other.

Comment: @DamianSchenkelman I understand you fine. At first i thought it was the answer to my question, but actually it solves the 'unresponsive ui' problem. I tried wrapping everything in task run and while it works, it does raise few other problems. ive updated the answer to include my latest progress. Thanks.